# Can i use core data and sqlite3 in a single application iOS

Tags: ios

Currently I'm working on a project where I need to use coredata (I know that coredata internally uses sqlite). In the future I need to merge this project with my existing project where I used sqlite. So, would it be a problem while I merge this project which uses core data and the previous project which I was using sqlite3 into one single application. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No problem with that approach, You will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not "just" merge, but you can manually query your CoreData sqlite and map the results into your "native" sqlite accordingly.

If your existent sqlite should go into CoreData, then do it the other way around.

Try to avoid to reverse-engineer the CoreData sqlite shuffling your entries manually into it. Pass  your sqlite query results through the managedObjectContext and be done for good.